# How to insert a long integer to postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a struts application using postgresql as back end. i want to insert a 8 digit number into the database, not a decimal number. At back end i have used numeric(8,0). setting the value like:

```
    PreparedStatement psmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO bank.chequebook("
        + "issueno, issuedate, accountno, fromno, tono, username)"
        + "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        System.out.println("Qrr"+psmt);
        psmt.setString(1,cb.getIssueNo());
        psmt.setDate(2,cb.getIssueDate());
        psmt.setString(3,cb.getAccountNo());
        psmt.setLong(5, cb.getToNo());
```

this results in null pointer exception.
i have tried bigInteger also. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Please append the whole statement creation code and the stack trace.

Comment: which line gives null pointer exception

Comment: The NPE is there probably during unboxing of `Long` returned from `cb.getToNo()`...

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion, first of all

```
psmt !=null

check cb!=null
```

and then

```
cb.getToNo()!=null
```

and try to put hard code value for testing.